# mouseenter while display:none is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` that is hidden when the page loads (usling `display: none;`) and I want it to fadeIn and out while the mouse comes over it. Unfortunately, the `mouseenter` event does not get sent while the css attribute `display: none;` is set. Is there a workaround to this?

```
div.overlay {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 860px;
    height: 279px;

    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);

    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -279px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

EDIT: the page I'm talking about is here: http://alexzielenski.com/v2/
I am trying to fade in the productDescription div when you mouseover the slider

Comment: position: absolute; + visibility: hidden; = display: none;

Comment: I tried this just now and it didn't work.

Comment: I dont get you. The div in question has display: none; on page load. That means it is taken out of the "Normal Flow" of the document as well as it is hidden from view. Now you want the "same" div to have display: block on mouseover event on the "same" div so that it show's in view?

Comment: I just opened it and it worked fine. If you are using internet explorer: it is not really made to display correctly on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            div.overlay {
                visibility: hidden;
                display: block;
                width: 860px;
                height: 279px;

                background-color: rgb(0,0,0);

                position: relative;
                margin-top: -279px;

                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div onmouseenter="alert('now animate the div inside');">
            <div class="overlay">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The below won't work since neither "visibility : hidden" or "display : none" will trigger any mouse events:

```
display: block; visibility: hidden
```

The problem is that using

```
display: none
```

will not render the object to the document.

Comment: Not exactly right. It doesn't remove it from the document, it just prevents it from being displayed.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Like my comment on one of the other answers, Google Chrome highlights where the element should be when I hover over its code using "inspect element" but the events arent sent.

Comment: I added the URL of this page in the original post

Comment: Don't understand why an incorrect answer like this receives votes-up

Comment: Maybe someone wants the "max votes" badge? I think I figured out a way around it at least... and I learnt something new!

Comment: Asken, I tried your new code and it didn't work either. Maybe something I am doing with the way my page is coded is stopping the visibility: hidden trick from working. The containing div is not getting sent the mouseenter event. Slidesjs might be doing something funny.

Comment: Provide some slimmed down code that reflects your problem and I'm sure we'll all figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility: hidden` instead. If you have `display: none` there's no element on which to hover over.

Comment: This still doesn't work. On Google Chrome, inspect element highlights where the view is supposed to be, but mouseenter/exit events are not sent. I've updated my original post with code

Answer (score 0):

When you make an element `display:none`, it isn't displayed at all on the page. Therefore, there is no way for the mouse to hover over it. Ultimately, you want to simply set the opacity to 0 and then animate the opacity. However, it should be noted that this may affect the layout of your page because now the element *will* take up space, as opposed to when it has `display:none`. If the element is absolutely positioned, however, then you should be ok.

Using `visibility:hidden`, like other answers here suggest, would also work. But it wouldn't allow you to fade in the element. It would simply just appear or disappear, no animation.

Comment: Yeah, previously I was animating the opacity but it did not work on Internet Explorer 8 and below. Animating opacity using the directX filter might also work but I'd prefer to have something working for all browsers.

Comment: Animating opacity works fine in IE8 unless it's animating a png with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the fade-out hook on the element itself so it will fade out when the user hovers out of it but the fade-in event need to be on a different element such as a parent or sibling because the element is not in the page any more after faded out.

for instance a pop-up fades in when you hover an image and stays until you hover-out of the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Element which has `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden` **can't** receive mouse or keyboard event. You should add an overlay div without content & has `background: transparent;` which has the same position and dimension as the div you want to fade in. Bind `mouseenter` event on the overlay div and do what you want.

Comment: Tried this, it added a usability issue with the slider

Comment: When you click the arrow the overlay coming in would always be displayed even if the overlay of the current slide was not displayed.